# JS функция подскажите ошибку

Tags: javascript, функции

```js
start.onclick = function unique(arr) {
  var obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var str = arr[i];
    obj[str] = true; // запомнить строку в виде свойства объекта
  }

  return Object.keys(obj); 
}

var strings = document.getElementById("strings");
alert(unique(strings));
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <h4>Введите текст</h4>
    <textarea id="strings" type="text" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea><br />
    <input type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-success" name="delete" value="Удалить дубликаты" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо лучше изучить [объявление функций](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#definition).
То способ, которым вы объявили (и сразу присвоили свойству `onclick`) функцию не сохраняет и не подымает её в глобальной области видимости, поэтому, когда вы пытаетесь вызвать её по имени - вам выдаёт абсолютно логичную ошибку, о том что функция `unique` не определена.

Попробуйте так:

```js
function getUnique(s) {
  return [...new Set(s.split("\n"))].join("\n")
}

start.onclick = () => {
  strings.value = getUnique(strings.value)
}

setTimeout(() => {
  strings.value = getUnique(strings.value)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <h4>Введите текст</h4>
    <textarea id="strings" rows="10">
qwe
qwe
asd
asd
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-success" name="delete" value="Удалить дубликаты" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Этот код делает именно то, что вы хотели, но делает это лаконично и безопасно. Попробуйте понять, что здесь происходит, и вам будет проще изучить язык.

Удачи!